# unittest - assertRaises return an error instead of passing

Tags: python, python-unittest

I've written a piece of code that uses a config file (in JSON-format)

```
def test_read_config_file(self):
   self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.read_config_file('no_json.txt')
```

The original function looks like this:

```
def read_config_file(file_name)
    config_data = None

    try:
       with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
         config_data = json.load(infile)
    except ValueError as err:
       LOGGER.error(str(err))

    return config_data
```

When i run my testcase i get this:

```
2016-07-27 12:41:09,616 ERROR read_config_file(158) No JSON object could be decoded
2016-07-27 12:41:09,616 ERROR read_config_file(158) No JSON object could be decoded
2016-07-27 12:41:09,616 ERROR read_config_file(158) No JSON object could be decoded
2016-07-27 12:41:09,616 ERROR read_config_file(158) No JSON object could be decoded
```

no_json.txt just contains "Hi". Why am i getting 4 error here?

Thanks,

Comment: what did you expect? "Hi" is not valid json, so the error is logged. It does not seem to be the test result. Rather it looks like a print.

Comment: In the documentation there is an example which uses the `with` statement to handle the assertion. Also your `read_config_file` function handles the exception by logging it. If you want your function to raise ValueError after logging then you should re-raise it by writing `raise` after the logging in the exception clause.

Comment: @Zazz you should accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `unittest` library correctly. When you write this:

```
def test_read_config_file(self):
   self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.read_config_file('no_json.txt'))
   # Btw. there was a missing closing `)`
```

the `self.read_config_file()` method is executed before the `self.assertRaises`. If it fails the `self.assertRaises` will never be called. Instead the exception bubbles up until something else catches it.

You want the `self.assertRaises` method to execute the `self.read_config_file` method. Because then and only then it can catch a potential `ValueError`. To do this you have two options:

Pass the method to test and the arguments separately:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.read_config_file, "no_json.txt")
```

Like this `self.assertRaises` will call the function you passed into it with the arguments specified. Then the exception occurs inside `self.assertRaises` where it can be caught and let the test succeed.

The second option is to use a context manager:

```
def test_read_config_file(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        self.read_config_file("no_json.txt")
```

Like this the exception will happen inside the `with` statement. In the cleanup step of the context manager the presence of such an exception can then again let the test succeed.

**EDIT:**
From your edit i can see that you already handle the `ValueError` in your `self.read_config_file` method. So any `self.assertRaises` approach will fail anyway. Either let the `self.read_config_file` raise the error or change your test.

Comment: Hmm...Isn't the point of assertRaises to check if a function that throws an exception actually throws that exception when something bad happens? Or am i missing something here?

Comment: Yes, assertRaises __fails__ if the expected exception was __not__ raised. But the two problems in your code (incorrect usage of assertRaises and not even throwing the exception in the code to text) make that test pointless. Was something in my answer not clear enough? Please point out anything that is unclear and I will try to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function catches the `ValueError` exception that `json.load` raises, performs the logging, then simply goes on to return the value of `config_data`. Your test asserts that the function should raise an exception, but there is no code to ensure that the function does that.

The easiest way to fix this would be to modify the code by adding a `raise` statement to ensure that the `ValueError` is re-raised to be trapped by the `assertRaises` call:

```
def read_config_file(file_name)
    config_data = None

    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
            config_data = json.load(infile)
    except ValueError as err:
        LOGGER.error(str(err))
        raise

    return config_data
```